# HTML Service does not open a sidebar in V8 runtime

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8

I have a very large project running on Rhino, but when I switch it to V8 one of the basic functionalities breaks - the sidebar in Google Sheets can no longer be opened.

Basic architecture:

**A)** Google Sheet A with a script (Rhino) importing a GAS Library (V8). The sidebar is in the Library.

versus

**B)** Google Sheet B with a script (V8) importing a GAS Library (V8). The sidebar is in the Library.

---

This code is in the Library (standalone script file, running in V8):

```
// called from parent script as LIB.showSidebar()
function showSidebar() {
  try {
    var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("sidebar/sidebarClient.html")
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle("tools sidebar");
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
  } catch (error) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Couldn't render sidebar: " + error);
    return;
  }
}
```

The previous library function is ran from the parent Sheet A/B script via the "LIB" namespace descriptor:

```
// simple trigger
function onOpen(e) {
  buildMenu();
}

//  builds menu
function buildMenu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu("My menu")
    .addItem("Open sidebar", "openSidebar")
    .addToUi();
}

// opens sidebar
function openSidebar() {
  LIB.showSidebar();
}
```

Behavior:

**A)** Everything works fine, the code above opens up the Sidebar in Sheet A as expected.

**B)** The result is an alert showing:

> "Couldn't render sidebar: Exception: Not found."

Switching the script in Sheet B back to Rhino solves the issue, and the Sidebar opens in Sheet B too.

Therefore, the issue is the switch to V8.

Is the filename in the form of a path the issue on V8 (*"sidebar/sidebarClient.html"*)? I'm using clasp to sync files into subfolders - it's really a huge project and I can't (or rather refuse to) do without that.

---

I tried using the filename with and without the .html extension, and with and without the path. The behavior is the same (all variations of the file path "sidebar/sidebarClient", "sidebar/sidebarClient.html", "sidebarClient" and "sidebarClient.html" behave the same, opening in sheet A, not found in sheet B).

Anyone got any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Well try plain `sidebarClient` without the path and plain html file and see whether that fixes the issue?

Comment: Possibly related to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194).

Comment: I created a new issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150054572

I see the issue tracker is littered with V8-related bugs, so I guess it's just another in the list. :(

Comment: You can add the link as a answer in the answerbox below

Answer (score 4):

I also opened an issue on Google's Issue Tracker, currently still unresolved: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150054572