# Switching from Rhino to V8 causes Error code PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-addon, google-slides, google-apps-script-runtime

Recently I switched my google slides script runtime from `Rhino` to `V8`. I tested my Add-on but I got an error:

> `We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED`.

My script uses `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()`. I found out that I had to logout from my google account and login again and it **worked**.

I can imagine that this could be pain also for other users who are using this add-on. Is there any other way how to fix this error?

`appscript.json` config

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Bratislava",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Also I am developing add-on localy on my PC nad using [clasp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp) to push the code to the App script.

### Update

I created minimal project to reproduce this error and I found out that `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` was not the issue. Turns out that after switching from `Rhino` to `V8`,  I am not able to call any appscript functions.

```
// Code.gs
function onInstall(event) {
    onOpen(event);
}

function onOpen(event) {
    SlidesApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Open the sidebar', '_showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
    _showSidebar();
}

function _showSidebar() {
    var ui = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setTitle('Test add-on');
    SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function getCurrentSlideObjectId() {
    var page = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSelection().getCurrentPage();
    if (page && page.getPageType() === SlidesApp.PageType.SLIDE) {
        return page.getObjectId();
    }
    return null;
}
```

With template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script>
       const onButtonClick = () => {
         google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(success)
          .withFailureHandler(error)
          .getCurrentSlideObjectId()
       }
       const success = (currentSlideObjectId) => {
         console.log("It works!", currentSlideObjectId);
       }
       const error = (error) => {
         error = typeof error === 'string' ? new Error(error) : error;
         console.error(typeof error === 'object' && error !== null ? error.message : error);
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently I am logged into my google drive with 2 different accs. When testing the add-on on different acc than Google chrome is logged in, an error will come out.

> `We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED`.

Comment: Why do you want to use [tag:V8]? I mean, is there an specific benefit that you are looking for ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60453863/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/60356124/1595451

Comment: @Rubén Better performance, ES6, better logging and possibly fixing of some bugs like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61576767/g-suite-add-on-refusing-to-connect-to-drive-how-to-solve-drive-google-com-refu) also we had a problems with minified code (can't remember the details)

Comment: Have you seen the links on my last comment?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453863/slides-app-getactivepresentation-error-after-v8-migration) I also use 2 different accounts 1 in chrome browser and the other in google drive. But this was not problem with Rhino.

Comment: Just curious but by any chance were you logged into another account with the same browser when this happened?

Comment: Yes, my browser uses different acc than my google drive login (well... I am using 2 google accs for my drive). And this does not occure in incognito mode.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue by Google IssueTracker that [an add-on can lead to `PERMISSION_DENIED` under certain conditions](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150247026), you could go ahead and click `+1` to increase the issue popularity. As [Rubén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/rub%c3%a9n) said, this issue could also follow [multiple logged users](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69270374) so go ahead and use the `+1` if your scenario is similar to that thread.